# Can a neighbourhood of a point be an singleton set?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Can a neighbourhood of a point be a singleton set containing that point only ? I think yes.

Would you construct examples of such a neighbourhood?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an extreme example, let $X$ be say the natural numbers, with metric $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\ne y$, and $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$. Then *every* point has a neighbourhood that consists only of that point.

Comment: For that sake $X$ could be the natural numbers with the standard metric, $d(x, y) = |y-x|$.

Answer (score 4):

To offer an even more extreme example than André Nicolas, consider a metric space $X$ that **has** only one point: that is, $X=\{x\}$ and the metric $d\colon X\times X\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $d(x,x)=0$.

What are the subsets of $X$? Are any of them neighborhoods of the point $x$?