# Is a point a neighbourhood?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In this question [Can a neighbourhood of a point be an singleton set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474746/can-a-neighbourhood-of-a-point-be-an-singleton-set) The answers indicate that a point is a neigbourhood. But would this therefore not mean that every (continuous) function is analytic? Since the definition of an analytic function is one where the taylor series converges to $f(x)$ for $x$ in a neighbourhood of $x_0$ (the point we are considering). But a taylor series around $x_0$ will always converge on to $f(x_0)$ (if done as we are assuming around the point $x_0$) at $x=x_0$. Since $x_0$ is itself a neighbourhood then every function should be analytic.

Answer (score 1):

a singleton can be a neighbourhood of the point in it. it depends on the topology defined on your space. i would take that without the loss of generality, analytic functions live in $\mathbb R$ with the standard topology induced by the standard metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$  and in that case it is easy to verify that a singleton is not a neighbourhood of the point in it. (since it has no open subset that contain the point in it, since a singleton  is not open(in the standard topology))

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the topology. A neighborhood of a $x_0$ is an open set containig $x_0$. In the discreet topology, every point is an open set
and so $x_0$ would be a neighborhood. If we look at $\Bbb R$ with the usual order topology, this would no longer be true.

Comment: A more general definition of _neighborhood_ often used says $N$ is a neighborhood of a point $x_0$ iff $x_0 \in U \subseteq N$ for some open set $U$. Otherwise, your answer is correct, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If points are open, the topology is called *discrete*: every subset is open. Therefore, every function on a discrete topological space is continuous.

But that's about as far as you can go and still say something interesting.  If $Y$ is a normed linear space (you need that or some similar structure in order to take a derivative), then $f\colon X \to Y$ is differentiable in the sense that
$$
\lim_{x\to a} \frac{\Vert f(x) - f(a)\Vert}{d(x,a)} 
$$
exists.  On the other hand, the numerator tends to zero, while the denominator is one whenever $x\neq a$.  Therefore this limit is 0 for any $f$.

So yes, every function is differentiable, but every derivative is zero, which makes it not a very useful object.